# how to write use cases of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to write a use cases to test the asp.net mvc applicatoin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just further to what @Keith has said, Use Cases should be platform independant and should be the same for Web, Windows Apps, Cars etc etc.

Writing a use case should be a simple set of tasks that can be extrapolated into a feature of the application you are writing.

If you are writing test cases then that's different.  We write our tests here to test individual functionaility and then we write further tests to test integration which ensures two things.

Firstly that the actual methods perform as expected and any changes to code in or away from these methods does not break them or if they do break then they are modified accordningly.

Secondly that the integration of our various layers work as advertised and any changes made to core methods does not break the core architecture.

Answer (score 1):

use cases and tests are slightly different things

A use case defines what an application should do / its requirements

So a use cases might be

"User can sign up to a website"
"User wants to recover/reset password"

etc..

in asp.net mvc you should have controllers that satisfy your use case requirements and can write unit tests to validate that they do the right thing.

or you can use something like Watir or Selenium to validate a running website

or perhaps even something like Fit over the top of that to have use case traceability to tests.

Comment: hmm thanks for your time..here my requirement is to create use cases and created some prototypes for the application..i am think from you i got pretty much answer.. i will post if i need more about this.. 
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

[Writing Effective Use Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201702258) should demistify use cases for you. Also, check out [Asp.Net MVC Test Driven Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470447621) and [The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274)